# Delegate pattern

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to understand how delegate pattern works.  Below is some code that I tried, but the problem is that the delegate methods downloadStarted and downloadFinished are never invoked.

What I miss here ?

DownloaderDelegate.h

```
@protocol DownloaderDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)downloadStarted;
-(void)downloadFinished;
@end
```

Downloader.h

```
#import "DownloaderDelegate.h"

@interface Downloader : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<DownloaderDelegate>delegate;
-(void)fileIsDownloaded;
-(void)downloadFile;
@end
```

Downloader.m

```
@implementation Downloader
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;


-(void)downloadFile
{
    [[self delegate] downloadStarted];

    [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 
                            target:self 
                            selector:@selector(fileIsDownloaded) 
                            userInfo:nil 
                            repeats:NO];
}


-(void)fileIsDownloaded
{
    [[self delegate]downloadFinished];
}
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        ....
        Downloader *d = [[Downloader alloc]init];
        [d downloadFile];
        [d release];
        ....
    }

-(void)downloadStarted
{
    NSLog(@"Started");
}

-(void)downloadFinished
{
    NSLog(@"Finished");
}
```

Comment: Read this - [Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AppDelegate` needs to implement the `DownloaderDelegate` protocol:

`@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,DownloaderDelegate>`

and then, when you instantiate the downloader, make the `AppDelegate` its delegate.

`d.delegate = self;`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add [d setDelegate:self]. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First you change the property of your delegate to "**assign**", it doesn't need reatin.
Then set the **d.delegate = self;(or the class you neeeded)**.then only you can access the delegate at that class.
In the .h file of the class where you needed the delegate, you have to include the delegate
eg:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate,DownloaderDelegate>
```